# How to get a list of of objects of a Django model using a field that itself is a foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Currently, my models look like this:

```
class MainCategory(models.Model):
    main_category = models.CharField(max_length = 25)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.main_category)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.main_category) + ' | ' + self.sub_category

class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
```

I am doing things this way to keep everything separated and accessible independently. So, some articles have the main category 'Entertainment'.
That is, self.category.main_category = 'Entertainment'. My question is, how do I get all the articles that have the same main_category?

I tried Article.objects.filter(category__main_category = 'Entertainment'), but that does not seem to work. 
The error is invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Entertainment'
Any ideas?

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice question. It would be great if you accepted the answer that solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your models, seems it's:

```
Article.objects.filter(category__main_category__main_category='Entertainment')
```

You have some indirection in your models, so here's a diagram:

```
Article.objects.filter(category__main_category__main_category='Entertainment')
                       ^         ^               ^ 
                       |         |               |_ MainCategory.main_category
                       |         |_ Subcategory.main_category
                       |_ Article.category
```

Your error `The error is invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Entertainment'` is simply because you were querying for `category__main_category` which is an FK to `Subcategory` so it was trying to convert that to a primary key (e.g. an `int`)

Django docs on relationships querying https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `category__main_category` expects a `MainCategory` instance or its primary key. So it should be:

```
Article.objects.filter(category__main_category__main_category = 'Entertainment')
```

Also to get *"all the articles that have the same main_category"* you would have to actually do

```
Article.objects.filter(category__main_category=category_instance)
```

where `category_instance` sholud be selected from a category list provided somewhere to the app user. Otherwise you are just searching by main category name which does not identify a category because it is not marked as primary key or unique.